# Múltiplos aplicativos em um mesmo domínio Nginx

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx, joomla

Bom dia galera, estou quebrando a cabeça aqui.

Tenho um servidor com nginx e nele tenho duas aplicações:

1 - Aplicativo Laravel
/usr/share/nginx/html/laravel/public

2 - Aplicativo Joomla
/usr/share/nginx/html/joomla

O aplicativo em Laravel é o principal que deve ser acessado em 'http://domain.com.br/' e o joomla deve ser acessado em 'http://domain.com.br/antigo'.

Abaixo segue o código de configuração do default:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html/laravel/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;

server_name 104.131.92.76;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ /antigo/ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/joomla;
    index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Tenta alterar `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` para `try_files $uri $uri/ /antigo/index.php?$args;`.

Comment: Faz um teste
no terminal executa
`nginx -t` se estiver com erro seu conf. vai te mostrar em qual linha está errado.

Answer (score 1):

Na linha `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` você está mandando todas as requisições que dão erro em `dominio.com.br/antigo/*` para `dominio.com.br/index.php` da sua outra aplicação. Esse é um erro fácil de ver.

Se você vai querer manter roteamento ideal tanto para o Joomla quanto para o laravel (em vez de manter apenas um deles ligado) em um mesmo domínio, pode ser bem trabalhoso fazer isso funcionar.

Aqui tem documentação de como fazer isso usando Joomla na raiz do domínio https://docs.joomla.org/Nginx

Comment: Amigo e como eu faria o contrário? Vários domínios e o mesmo aplicativo?? O aplicativo seria em Vue.js e deveria receber um parâmetro diferente para cada domínio.

Comment: Provavelmente mais fácil do que a pergunta acima. Mas nesse caso, melhor abrir uma pergunta dedicada para o que precisa (caso já não o tenha feito).